# Gumroad Embedded Widget breaks on navigation in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mutation-observers

I want to include [Gumroad's **Embed** Widgets](https://gumroad.com/widgets) in my Angular application.

**What I've tried:**

I added this to my **index.html**:

```
<script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad-embed.js"></script>
```

I added this to one of my components' template:

```
<div class="gumroad-product-embed" data-gumroad-product-id="demo"><a href="https://gumroad.com/l/demo">Loading...</a></div>
```

**The problem:**

Let's say the component on page `/buy`. If I open `/buy`, the widget appears. However, if I've navigated to `/buy` through some `routerLink` in the app, the widget doesn't appear, it just keeps showing "Loading...".

I also confirmed this by changing `routerLink` to `href` and it worked. I.e., the problem is probably related to removal and re-adding of the div.

Anyway, my question: how to use Gumroad's Embed Widget inside an Angular application correctly?

**Notes:**

1- It could be useful to look at `gumroad-embed.js`. It has stuff like `MutationObserver` but I couldn't follow along.

2- The Angular application is running on electronjs, in case that'll make a difference (due to `MutationObserver` or anything else).

Comment: I have the same problem with vue on client side navigation 

Comment: I'd sent them this StackOverflow question a year ago and they sent it to the team but seems like it never got prioritized. Perhaps if you reach out to them on support@gumroad.com with this question, it may help them assess how many people are affected. In the end, I think I just used a normal link & a button and gave up on using it :(

Comment: Same problem in React :/

Answer (score 0):

Till someone comes up with a better answer, here's a solution that works *specifically* with the current `gumroad-embed.js`. In the future, it could change and the answer would be obsolete. Anyway, here it is:

### Solution

1) Add a file `edited-gumroad-embed.js` under your `/assets` containing the following code:

```
function createGumroadEmbed(){window.GumroadEmbed||(window.GumroadEmbed=new GumroadEmbedManager)}function receiveMessage(t){var e={};if(t.data)try{e=JSON.parse(t.data)}catch(r){}if("GumroadEmbedMessage"===e.type&&GumroadEmbed){var i=GumroadEmbed.findEmbed(e.args.id)||GumroadEmbed.findEmbed(e.args.unique_id);i&&("setHeight"===e.action?i.setHeight(e.args.height):"scrollToTop"===e.action&&i.scrollToTop())}}!function(){var n=!1,a=/xyz/.test(function(){})?/\b_super\b/:/.*/;this._GumroadClass=function(){},_GumroadClass.extend=function(t){function e(){!n&&this.init&&this.init.apply(this,arguments)}var o=this.prototype;n=!0;var i=new this;for(var r in n=!1,t)i[r]="function"==typeof t[r]&&"function"==typeof o[r]&&a.test(t[r])?function(i,r){return function(){var t=this._super;this._super=o[i];var e=r.apply(this,arguments);return this._super=t,e}}(r,t[r]):t[r];return e.prototype=i,(e.prototype.constructor=e).extend=arguments.callee,e}}();var GumroadClass=_GumroadClass.extend({setEnvironment:function(){this.environment="production",this.domain="https://gumroad.com",this.isMobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile[\/; ]/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera (Mini|Mobi)/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i),this[this.environment]=!0,this.origin=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port?":"+window.location.port:"")},startNodeAdditionObserver:function(){MutationObserver&&(this.nodeAdditionObserver=new MutationObserver(function(t){for(var e=0;e<t.length;e++)for(var i=0;i<t[e].addedNodes.length;i++)this.nodeAdditionCallback&&this.nodeAdditionCallback(t[e].addedNodes[i])}.bind(this)),this.nodeAdditionObserver.observe(document.body,{childList:!0,subtree:!0}))}}),GumroadEmbedElement=GumroadClass.extend({init:function(t,e){this.manager=e;var i=t.getAttribute("data-gumroad-product-id");i&&(this.div=t,this.id=i,this.opts={as_embed:"true",referrer:document.referrer,origin:this.manager.origin},this.manager.embeds.push(this),this.show())},buildUrl:function(){var t=(this.manager.domain||"")+"/l/"+this.id+"?";for(var e in this.outboundEmbed&&(this.opts.outbound_embed="true"),this.opts)this.opts.hasOwnProperty(e)&&(t+="&"+e+"="+this.opts[e]);return t},createIframe:function(){this.iframe=document.createElement("iframe"),this.iframe.allowtransparency=!0,this.iframe.setAttribute("allowFullScreen","allowfullscreen"),this.iframe.className="gumroad-embed-iframe",this.iframe.scrolling="no",this.iframe.width="100%",this.iframe.height=0,this.iframe.id="gumroad-embed-iframe-"+this.id,this.iframe.setAttribute("style","display: block !important; border: none !important; margin: 0 auto !important; padding: 0 !important; max-width: 676px !important;"),this.div.parentNode.insertBefore(this.iframe,this.div)},scrollToTop:function(){this.iframe&&this.manager.isMobile&&window.scrollTo(0,this.iframe.offsetTop)},setHeight:function(t){this.div.style.display="none",this.iframe.setAttribute("height",t)},show:function(){this.iframe||this.createIframe();this.id=this.div.getAttribute("data-gumroad-product-id"),this.outboundEmbed=!!this.div.getAttribute("data-outbound-embed"),this.iframe.setAttribute("src",this.buildUrl())}}),GumroadEmbedManager=GumroadClass.extend({init:function(){this.setEnvironment(),this.createEmbeds()},createEmbeds:function(){this.embeds=[];for(var t=document.getElementsByClassName("gumroad-product-embed"),e=0;e<t.length;e++)new GumroadEmbedElement(t[e],this)},findEmbed:function(t){for(var e=0;e<this.embeds.length;e++)if(this.embeds[e].id==t)return this.embeds[e];return!1},gotMessage:function(t){var e={};try{e=JSON.parse(t.data)}catch(i){}this[e.action]&&this[e.action](e.args)},reload:function(){for(var t=0;t<this.embeds.length;t++){var e=this.embeds[t].iframe;e&&e.parentNode&&(e.parentNode.removeChild(e),this.embeds[t].div.style.display="")}this.createEmbeds()},scrollToTop:function(t){var e=this.findEmbed(t);e&&e.scrollToTop()},setHeight:function(t,e){var i=this.findEmbed(t);i&&i.setHeight(e)}});window.addEventListener?(window.addEventListener("message",receiveMessage,!1)/*,window.addEventListener("load",createGumroadEmbed)*/):window.attachEvent&&(window.attachEvent("onmessage",receiveMessage,!1)/*,window.attachEvent("onload",createGumroadEmbed)*/);createGumroadEmbed();
```

2) In the component whose template contains `<div class="gumroad-product-embed" data-gumroad-product-id="demo"><a href="https://gumroad.com/l/demo">Loading...</a></div>`, add the following code:

```
import {AfterContentInit, Component, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buy',
  templateUrl: './buy.component.html'
})
export class BuyComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterContentInit {

  readonly scriptNode: HTMLScriptElement;

  constructor() {
    this.scriptNode = document.createElement('script')
    this.scriptNode.setAttribute('src','/assets/edited-gumroad-embed.js')
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(this.scriptNode)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.scriptNode.remove()
    delete window['GumroadEmbed']
  }
}
```

3) Success!

### Explanation

By looking into `gumroad-embed.js`, it seems, *as of Nov. 2018*, to be just including another file. This other file's code is the base on which `edited-gumroad-embed.js` is based. `edited-gumroad-embed.js` is basically this file with 2 edits:

1. It calls `createGumroadEmbed()` instead of calling it on `load` event directly, because `load` seems to be firing once only at initial load of document.
2. It comments the event listener for `load` that used to call `createGumroadEmbed()`.

For the component ts file, it basically tries to simulate the loading of the script as much as possible as if it was first load. By taking a *non-thorough* look into gumroad's code, it seems like for actions to happen `window.GumroadEmbed` needs to be `undefined`; that's why it deletes `window['GumroadEmbed']`.

### Open questions and caveats

There's are enough open questions to pass a camel through.

1. Is all of that even needed or should have original Gumroad's code succeeded had it been run on Chrome instead of electronjs?
2. I didn't take enough look into gumroad's code to know if what I'm doing has no side effects. For example, are there leaks? are there event listeners that should be removed? What about the `MutationObserver`(s)?
3. I'm not sure why I'm calling the code in `ngAfterContentInit`. I'm trying to make it run after the `div` has been added to the DOM as much as possible.
4. If the component is reused (for example, in routing), does one need to re-create the `scriptNode`? I currently have routing reuse disabled anyway for other reasons.

That said, I'm probably not intending to use it after all, but the reason is unrelated to the original question. The reason is that I found many requests in the Network tab to many websites (e.g., Facebook) and I don't know the effect of that on my customers (e.g., privacy-wise). Again: I do *not* know, I'm not familiar with `iframe`s. Also, I'm a bit afraid that my solution might have any leaks.

I'll just add a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in React, and came up with this simple solution:

`index.html:`

```
<script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad-embed.js"></script>
<div style="display:none;" id="gumroad-product-embed" class="gumroad-container">
    <div class="gumroad-product-embed" data-gumroad-product-id="gwIwi">
        <a href="https://gumroad.com/l/gwIwi">Loading...</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script defer>
  const embed = document.getElementById('gumroad-product-embed')
  window.GUMROAD = embed
</script>
```

`<gumroadcomponent>.js:`

```
const gumroad = window.GUMROAD
const container = React.createRef()

export class BuyNUNISYNTH extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        gumroad.style.display = "block"
        container.current.appendChild(gumroad)
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <MyNav no_buy_button/>
            <div ref={container}></div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

This keeps the Gumroad embed outside of React so that it only needs to load once. It was the re-rendering of React that was causing the problem.